# Cypress tests with mocha multi reports; not able to get aggregated results for all test spec

Tags: mocha.js, cypress, test-results

## Cypress tests with mocha multi reports don't show results from all the tests

My test structure looks like so:
*cypress

  integration

    module1

      module1test1_spec.js

      module1test1_spec.js

    module2

      module2test1_spec.js

      module2test1_spec.js*

I have set up Cypress to use mocha-multi-reports like in instruction provided under 
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters.html#Multiple-Reporters
My config.json looks exactly like here:
 https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-docker-circle#spec--xml-reports
When Cypress finishes testing, results.xml file shows results from last test spec **ONLY**; module2test1_spec.js
**How to configure this to get the aggregated results from all test spec?**

Comment: Try this method It will work 100%, https://softans.com/using-mochawesome-reporter-with-cypress/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [hash].xml in your path.

e.g. ./path_to_your/test-results.[hash].xml. [hash] is replaced by MD5 hash of test results XML. This enables support of parallel execution of multiple mocha-junit-reporter's writing test results in separate files.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-junit-reporter#results-report

I solved this problem with this way.

my config.json file seems like this:

```js
"reporterEnabled": "spec,json, mocha-junit-reporter",
  "mochaJunitReporterReporterOptions": {
    "mochaFile": "multiple-results/[hash].xml",
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer above, if you would like to merge all these multiple `[hash].xml` created into a single `mergedreport.xml` report, then you can use this package [junit-report-merger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/junit-report-merger) which is useful for running it on CI pipeline which usually looks for a single reporter with a command like the one below:

`jrm ./cypress/reports/mergedreport.xml "./cypress/reports/*.xml"`